# regexp pattern to recognize the Fortran numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, fortran

I have numbers with the following formats

- integers like : `1, 2, 3`
- float like    : `1.23, 1.23e2, 1.23d3`
- integer with kind: `12_ip, 15_kp`
- float with kind:   `1.23_wp, 1.23e2_wp, 1.23d2_wp`

what JavaScript regexp pattern can recognize these numbers? I found something like below:

```
 x=   '(?=\\b|\\+|\\-|\\.)(?=\\.\\d|\\d)(?:\\d+)?(?:\\.?\\d*)(?:[de][+-]?\\d+)?\\b\\.?'
```

But it fails to recognize `1.23_wp` or `12_kp`.

Comment: As a (truly) minor point: `1.23d2_wp` isn't a valid literal.  If a kind specifier is given the exponent symbol must be `e` (or `E`).

Comment: A regex for a concatenation is the concatenation of regexes.  In other words OP needs to plug a regex to recognise `_wp` (etc) onto the end of the existing regex.  But it looks as if OP didn't write that regex, couldn't write that regex, couldn't extend it and is expecting someone else to do that for her.  Come on, make a bit of an effort.

Comment: @francescalus, that's right!

Comment: The pattern will be used in ajavascript code to recognize fortran number reading a text file.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark That's the usual problem with regexes, I deleted my previous rant, but it is more or less a write-only language to me.

Comment: Now that I read it again, it's very odd to encounter kind suffixes (e.g. `_wp`) in file which has been written by a Fortran program.  In fact I'm not sure I've ever encountered them outside source code.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, yes the javascript code reads the fortran source file! It should recognize numbers in the fortran source file. This is a question regarding regexp pattern for javascript!

Comment: for anyone working this the kind name ( `kp` , `wp` ) can be any length (max 63 char ).  Also (somewhat pathologically) there can be spaces in there, `1.23  _  k`   ( fixed form fortran actually allows `1  .  2   3  _  k p` )

Comment: @agentp, can you support the claim that `1.23 _ wp` is valid in free form source?

Comment: not per standard, only that gfortran takes it. Just for fun It permits continuation lines before and after the underscore as well. In any case I think you could probably ignore that and flog the programmer that did such things.

Comment: That makes me sad :(.  At least continuation (done correctly) _is_ allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I give it try:

[`\b[+-.]?\d+\.?\d*([de]\d+)?(_[wki]p)?\b`](https://regex101.com/r/36fDnD/1)

PS: I am not very familiar with very Fortran but I think `.1` and `1.5e-30` are common legal real numbers. The following improved pattern matches those too:

[`[+-]?(?:\.|\d+\.?)\d*(-?[de]\d+)?(_[wki]p)?\b`](https://regex101.com/r/36fDnD/2)

PS: I gave up the leading word boundary to match `.1`.

---

Use:

[`\[+-\]?(?:\.|\d+\.?)\d*(\[de\]\[+-\]?\d+)?(_\[a-z\d\]+)?\b`](https://regex101.com/r/36fDnD/4)

to also match

- Exponent with sign

```
1.23e-3
1.23d+5
```

- Custom precision with names like pr123 or myprecision, etc

```
1.23e3_pr123
1.23e+3_qwe098
1.23_myprecision
1.23e5_anyname
.23d+5
```

Comment: Thank you it works! There is some minor issues:
1.23e+2  1.23e-2
1.23d+2 1.23d-2

also, wp, ip, kp are examples any alphanumeric phrases (start with a letter) can be used so, 1.23_mynumber can be used!

Comment: I am glad to hear that. If you can provide a (online) sample we can tackle the minor issues or are we already good?

Comment: Now to match `1.23&  \n         &e56` (where that's a new line, not a real `\n`.

Comment: Ha, that looks though. Can this line continuation happen at any point? I think this is the moment you need a parser instead of a regex. You can add `&?\s*&?` in various places.

Comment: @wp78de, then you probably won't like `1.23& ! Why shouldn't I do this?\n!Hello 56\n                  &e56`.

Comment: Oh, there's also `1.2_8123` to consider.

Comment: @wp78de, I appreciate your help. It works for me, just please take a look at the example I shared above for those minor issues:

https://regex101.com/r/36fDnD/3

Thank you

Comment: @wp78de, everything is okay now! your solution works perfectly!
Many thanks for your time and help.